# Show data value instead of percentage in Flot pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm using http://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip. It shows percentages of data as below. But i need to show actual values instead of percentages. How can i do this ?

[image: chart]

**Json data**

> [{"data":350,"label":"Transport"},{"data":250,"label":"Meals"},{"data":250,"label":"Kitchen"},{"data":7280.5,"label":"Construction"},{"data":3725,"label":"Fuel"},{"data":160,"label":"Stationary"}]

**Script**

```
function make_chart() {

    $.ajax({
        cache : 'false',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : "piechart",
        success : function(json) {

            var plotObj = $.plot($("#flot-pie-chart"), json, {
                series: {
                    pie: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: {
                    content: "%p.0%, %s", // show percentages, rounding to 2 decimal places
                    shifts: {
                        x: 20,
                        y: 0
                    },
                    defaultTheme: false
                }
            });             

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just modify the the `tooltipOpts: content` property; replacing the `%p` with `%y`:

```
tooltipOpts: {
  content: "%y.0, %s", // show value to 0 decimals
  shifts: {
      x: 20,
      y: 0
  },
  defaultTheme: false
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UsQ8x/).

Or use a function for more flexibility:

```
content: function(label,x,y){
    return y+", "+label;
},
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UsQ8x/1/).

Comment: @Bishan, does my linked fiddle work for you?  Which browser are you seeing the `%y` in?

Comment: Your link is working fine. But when run my project, i'm seeing `%y `. I'm using chrome.

Comment: @Bishan, that is strange.  Are all your versions up to date? My fiddle uses flot 0.8.3 and tooltip 0.7.1.  What if you change content to what I have in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UsQ8x/1/ (also see updated answer)?

Comment: I'm using flot 0.7 and tooltip 0.6.2. i think it should be the issue. i'll update and try :)

Comment: is there any way to format data value ? now it show as 7281, 352 etc.. i need to show them as 7,281.00, 352.00

Comment: @Bishan, replace the .0 with .2

Comment: Thank you. now it show as 7281.00. but in need to show as  7,281.00. need to add commas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56327/discussion-between-bishan-and-mark).

Comment: Thanks, You make my day..!!